# How to source R code without overwriting current variables?

Tags: r

I am trying to retrieve results by executing R code with the `source` command. Because there are some variables with the same name, the variables in the executed R file will overwrite the current variables. How do I retrieve the result without overwriting the current variables?

```
#main.R Code
b=0
source('sub.R')
if(a>1){print(T)}else{print(F)}

#sub.R
b=1
test<-function(x){x=1}
a=test(b)
```

I want to only retrieve `a` from `sub.R` without `b` in `main.R` being overwritten by the same name variable in `sub.R`. Essentially, I want to execute a R file like calling a method with just keeping the return value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can source the contents into a specific environment with `sys.source` if you like. For example

```
b <- 0
ee <- new.env()
sys.source('sub.R', ee)
ee$a
# [1] 1     # the ee envir has the result of the sourcing
if(ee$a>1) {print(T)} else{print(F)}
# [1] FALSE
b
# [1] 0     #still zero
```

But if you're looking to source files like they are functions, you should just include a function in the sourced file and then call that function in your main file. Don't try to pass around values in the environment at all. For example

```
# sub.R  --------------
runsub<-function() {
    b=1
    test<-function(x){x=1}
    a=test(b)
    a
}

# main.R  -------------
b <- 0
source('sub.R')
a <- runsub()
if(a>1){print(T)}else{print(F)}
```

Or if you want to write a helper function to return a specific value from a sourced environment, you can do

```
sourceandgetvar <- function(filename, varname) {
    ee <- new.env()
    sys.source(filename, ee)
    stopifnot(varname %in% ls(envir=ee))
    ee[[varname]]
}
```

Then you can change main.R to

```
b <- 0
a <- sourceandgetvar("sub.R", "a")
if(a>1) {print(T)} else {print(F)}
# [1] FALSE
b
# [1] 0
```

Comment: can we pass a parameter to the sub.R by using sys.source command? Within sub.R, the passed parameter can be got like:
arg<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE) @MrFlick

Comment: If you're trying to pass parameters to a sourced file, you are not doing it correctly. You should be defining proper functions in the file you are sourcing.